# String Matches to Datatable

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I need to extract several pieces of information from a line of text that contains a certain key value. It seems like this would be a fairly common scenario, but I haven't been able to find much info that helps. Currently I am using select-string to find all lines that contain either "242200" or "242201". Once these lines are identified I am trying to extract parts of the line and put them into a datatable. I then need to sum two columns of the DT and export the result as CSV. This is what I have so far:

```
# Create a datatable to store the values in
$dataTable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable            

$dataTable.Columns.Add("Line Number")  | Out-Null
$dataTable.Columns.Add("Transaction Date")  | Out-Null
$dataTable.Columns.Add("ID")   | Out-Null
$dataTable.Columns.Add("Premium Tax State") | Out-Null            
$dataTable.Columns.Add("Amt1", [double]) | Out-Null            
$dataTable.Columns.Add("Amt2", [double]) | Out-Null            

ForEach($match in Select-String -path $SourceFile -pattern "242200", "242201") {

    # Convert the match OBJECT to a string
    $string = $match.Line

    $row = $datatable.NewRow()
    $row["Line Number"] = $match.LineNumber
    $row["Transaction Date"] = $string.substring(3,8)
    $row["ID"] = "MA4650654" #Need to find this in the string
    $row["Premium Tax State"] = $string.substring(32,34)

    # Determine the type and amount
    if ($string -match "242200") {
        $row["Amt1"] = 0 # Need to extract these amounts and sum them
        $row["Amt2"]  = 0
    }
    else {
        $row["Amt1"] = 0 
        $row["Amt2"]  = 0
    }

    $dataTable.Rows.Add($row)
}
```

Is there a better way to do this maybe through match groups or something?

EDIT: Sample Input

```
T0120131107004311         116212OK      0000000300000CYCLE 11/07/2013        JERAIEROKCAR0025593WTM
T0120131107004311         242200MO      0000000022782CYCLE 11/07/2013        MSDQONEAZCAR0012366RMM
T0120131107004311         242200NC      0000000040541CYCLE 11/07/2013        MSDQONENCCAR0033278WTM
T0120131107004311         242201FL      0000000084831CYCLE 11/07/2013        VIIEAMAFLCAR0025589RMM
```

Comment: Care to add some sample input and output data?

Comment: Wouldn't this be a lot easier if you'd create an array of PS Objects instead of a data table?

Comment: Which part(s) of the matching lines are you trying extract?

Comment: I added some sample data.

Comment: Lines 2-4 would be the lines that contain what I'm interested in. In line two I need the date 20131107 which is right after T01, then I need the state abbreviation MO, then 0000000022782 (the last two digits are decimal, this is currency) and I need CAR0012366 from near the end of the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this (Updated to work on V2):

```
$str = @"
T0120131107004311         116212OK      0000000300000CYCLE 11/07/2013        JERAIEROKCAR0025593WTM
T0120131107004311         242200MO      0000000022782CYCLE 11/07/2013        MSDQONEAZCAR0012366RMM
T0120131107004311         242200NC      0000000040541CYCLE 11/07/2013        MSDQONENCCAR0033278WTM
T0120131107004311         242201FL      0000000084831CYCLE 11/07/2013        VIIEAMAFLCAR0025589RMM
"@
$str -split "`n" | 
    Select-String -Pattern '^.{3}(.{8}).*?(?:242200|242201)(\w{2}).*?(.{10}).{3}\s*$' |
    Foreach {
        $_.matches | Foreach {$_.groups[1].value} # Date
        $_.matches | Foreach {$_.groups[2].value} # State
        $_.matches | Foreach {$_.groups[3].value} # Term at end
    }
```

Substitute your file for the string I'm using.

Comment: If the regex is confusing, use a tool like [Regex Coach](http://http://www.weitz.de/regex-coach/) to see which part does what. Oh, and I'd rather `(?:24220[01])` instead of `(?:242200|242201)`.

Comment: Sure that works for this particular combination but looking at the sample date the values can range broadly.  If the OP decided to later search for 116212 as well, it would be a bit more obvious how to add another search term.

Comment: Thanks Keith, if I understand this correctly, you're using one regex to capture all the info as groups. Am I on the right track? When I try to run this I get an error: **Cannot index into a null array.
At line:10 char:27
+         $_.matches.groups[ <<<< 1].value # Date**.

Comment: There's a feature difference between the, um, 4 year old V2 and V4 that I'm using.  :-)  I updated the answer with something that works in V2.

Comment: Thanks Keith, that made a difference. :)