# Combine Members on Custom Powershell Object

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am still working on a better approach to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19914231/string-matches-to-datatable) and I've decided to try creating a custom object which I can export to a csv. I have the basics working and can extract the info that I need, but now I would like to combine members that have a duplicate key value into one line. I've tried grouping on the ID field before exporting and using "if" statements to see if the ID number already exists and, if so, updateing the appropriate fields, but but I can't seem to get it to work. I also need to add a sum for each row.

```
$SourceFile = "C:\ACT20131107.TXT"
$objectCollection = ForEach($match in Select-String -path $SourceFile -pattern "242200", "242201") {      

# Convert the match OBJECT to a string for matching
$string = $match.Line

# Set variables
$Amt2 = "{0:n2}" -f 0
$Amt1 =  "{0:n2}" -f 0
$ID = $($string.substring(93,10)).replace("CAR","C")

if ($string -match "242200") {
    $Amt2 = $($string.substring(40,13)).Insert(11,'.')
}
else {
    $Amt1 = $($string.substring(40,13)).Insert(11,'.')
}

$properties = @{ID = $ID;Date = $string.substring(3,8);State = $string.substring(32,2);AmtF = $Amt1;AmtS = $Amt2} 
New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $properties                                       
} 

$objectCollection | export-csv "C:\test2.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Current Output:

```
ID       AmtF           AmtS           Date     State
--       ----           ----           ----     -----
C0044822 0.00           00000000227.82 20131107 MO   
C0010079 0.00           00000000405.41 20131107 NC   
C0027859 00000000848.31 0.00           20131107 FL   
C0010079 00000001291.00 0.00           20131107 MO   
C0044822 00000001351.35 0.00           20131107 NC
```

Desired Output:

```
ID       AmtF           AmtS           Date     State
--       ----           ----           ----     -----  
C0027859 00000000848.31 00000000000.00 20131107 FL   
C0010079 00000001291.00 00000000405.41 20131107 MO   
C0044822 00000001351.35 00000000227.82 20131107 NC  
Totals   00000003490.66 00000000633.23
```

This is the first time I've ever tried a custom object so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are really close. I have something that I think might work, but since I don't have any sample data in your original format, I can't know for sure.

It is not the prettiest solution, but I think it will get you where you want to go, without hopefully clobbering too much of your original code.

```
$SourceFile = "C:\ACT20131107.TXT"
# This hashtable is to store all unique ids and keep a running tally of AmtS and AmtF while you loop through the lines of the original file.
$dataHash = @{}

$objectCollection = ForEach($match in Select-String -path $SourceFile -pattern "242200", "242201") {      

# Convert the match OBJECT to a string for matching
$string = $match.Line

# Set variables
$Amt2 = "{0:n2}" -f 0
$Amt1 =  "{0:n2}" -f 0
$ID = $($string.substring(93,10)).replace("CAR","C")

if ($string -match "242200") {
    $Amt2 = $($string.substring(40,13)).Insert(11,'.')
}
else {
    $Amt1 = $($string.substring(40,13)).Insert(11,'.')
}

# In Powershell, 
if(!$dataHash.ContainsKey($ID))
{
    # This prevents you from trying to reference into a null collection in the next few lines.
    $dataHash[$ID] = @{}
}
# In Powershell, you can reference into a hashtable with a non existant key, and it will be added, and null values are the equivalent of 0 values for basic math ops.
$dataHash[$ID]["State"] = $string.substring(32,2);
$dataHash[$ID]["Date"] = $string.substring(3,8)
$dataHash[$ID]["AmtF"] += $Amt1
$dataHash[$ID]["AmtS"] += $Amt2
}

# Select out custom objects to make summations and csv export easier.
$properties = @(
    @{Name="ID";Expression={$_}},
    @{Name="Date";Expression={$dataHash[$_][Date]}}
    @{Name="AmtF";Expression={$dataHash[$_]["AmtF"]}}
    @{Name="Amts";Expression={$dataHash[$_]["AmtS"]}}
    @{Name="State";Expression={$dataHash[$_]["State"]}}
)
$dataForCsv = $dataHash.Keys | Select $properties

#Time to sum up, then add a custom object to the output data for the totals.
$AmtFTotals = ($dataForCsv | Measure-Object -Properties AmtF -Sum).Sum
$AmtSTotals = ($dataForCsv | Measure-Object -Properties AmtS -Sum).Sum
$dataForCsv += New-Object PSCustomObject @{ID="Totals";AmtF=$AmtFTotals;AmtS=$AmtSTotals;Date=$null;State=$null}
$dataForCsv | export-csv "C:\test2.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks Joseph. This worked out perfectly! I made a few minor edits to show exactly what I used. Hopefully someone else will find this useful.